# Flutter Flame Tiled Background Image wont fill screen

Tags: flutter, tiled, flame

Using Flutter with Flame both with the latest versions.  Trying to set a background image for the game.

In Tiled, I created a Tiled Map with a width of 120 and height of 68 using 16x16 Tile size.  I added an Image layer. I then added the image (1920x1080) to the Image Layer as shown here. As you can see the image fills the entire map. [image]

Saved the tmx file and loaded the map using in Flutter with:

```
 levelGrid =
    await TiledComponent.load('level2.tmx', Vector2.all(16));
```

The resulting game screen is below.  I added the small tree tiles in the corners to indicate the game actual screen size.  The background image does not fill the entire screen as it did in Tiled.

I also set the camera using

CameraComponent.withFixedResolution(width: 1920, height:1080 )

camera.viewfinder.anchor = Anchor.topLeft;

No matter what I try the image will not fill the map area.

[image]

Comment: For anyone else facing same problem, here is the same issue reported on the repo: https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/issues/2990